# PEP8 indentation warning in IntelliJ

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I have set my PEP8 indentation to 2 in IntelliJ. However, I still get the PEP8 indentation warning as not being of length 4. I went to 'Setting -> Editor -> Python ' and turned off the indentation warning. However, the inspector still continues to give me warnings.

Answer (score 12):

Go to `Settings | Editor | Inspections | PEP 8 Coding Style Violations` and add `E111` to the "Ignore Errors" list.

Comment: Also E114 (See http://pep8.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.7.x/intro.html )

Comment: You might want to also include E114 for indentation of comments

Comment: You can combine this with creating a more specific scope if you want it to only apply to a single file.