# How to enable PEP8 inspection in PyCharm IDE, except for using 2 spaces for indents?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, pep8

I've been using PyCharm IDE a lot recently when working with the TensorFlow Python repository. TensorFlow [follows the PEP8 Python style guide, except for using 2 spaces for indents](https://www.tensorflow.org/community/style_guide).

By default in PyCharm IDE I have the PEP8 inspection enabled to enable my codes follows PEP8 style convention. An undesirable side-effect is now I have warnings all over the place within PyCharm editor, flagging all indents (which are 2 spaces instead of 4 spaces).

If I disable PEP8 inspection, all warnings go away at the trade-off of no more PEP8 inspection (which is desirable).

Is there a way to enable full PEP8 inspection within PyCharm editor, but ignoring the 2-space indents?

Here is an example of the PEP8 warning (about indent spaces should be 4 not 2):

[image]

Here is a snapshot of PyCharm preferences page, under PEP8 inspection section (looks like it's either on/off - unless I'm missing something):

[image]

#### Updates

Two good options (for different purposes):

- the suggested "duplicated question" link works well if you'd like to ignore warnings at a PyCharm-wide level. (done within the Preference)
- the accepted answer works well if you'd only like to ignore warnings at current file / project level (without affecting other projects).

Comment: Have you considered Pycharm is right and you should use four spaces? Two spaces indentation gives many Python developer the shivers.

Comment: I do not have an opinion on this. The official Tensorflow repository uses 2 spaces as convention instead of 4 (I'm sure they did it for a reason) and I happen to be using PyCharm IDE (and PEP8 inspection tool). For this scenario I would rather just follow the Tensorflow convention and remove corresponding warnings in IDE - it's fit for purpose for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the cursor on the error being highlighted (e.g `raise` in your image) press `Alt + Enter` and choose `Ignore errors like this`

Comment: The [suggested duplicated solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386154/pep8-indentation-warning-in-intellij) works also - essentially adding [E111 code](http://pep8.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.7.x/intro.html) to the ignore error list at preference level. Great to have 2 options.

Comment: @Atlas7 You also have to add E114 so comments are not needed to be on multiple of 4 spaces. `Ignore errors like this` does this.

Comment: You can combine the [suggested duplicated solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386154/pep8-indentation-warning-in-intellij) with a more specific scope if you want to ignore the error in a single file (or set of files).